# Weak convergence of bounded operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, operator-algebras

so let $X$ be a Banach space then we say that $A_n \in L(X)$ converges weakly to $A \in L(X)$ if for all $y \in L(X)^*: y(A_n) \rightarrow y(A).$

On the other hand, I just read that weak convergence for operators is when $y'(A_nx) \rightarrow y'(Ax)$ for all $y' \in X'$ and $x \in X$ holds.

It is obvious that the first one implies the second one, as $y'(\cdot(x))$ is a continuous functional in $L(X)^*$, but is the second one actually equivalent to the first one? (Maybe if $X$ is a Hilbert space)?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not equivalent on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. The weak convergence for operators in this case is in the usually called "weak operator topology": 
$$
A_n\xrightarrow{wot} A\ \ \iff\ \ \langle A_nx,y\rangle\to\langle Ax,y\rangle,\ \ \forall x,y\in H.
$$
The weak operator topology is known to be coarser than the $\sigma$-weak operator topology, which is the one given by the normal functionals (which, among other characterizations, are precisely those wot-continuous on bounded sets). The weak topology is even finer, as it is given by all the functionals, including the non-normal ones (for instance, those that are zero on the compacts).